# logarithmic spaced values below 1

Tags: python, numpy

I want to plot values, in logarithmic scale, over the range 0.001 - 1000 (x axis); when I try:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.logspace(0.001, 1000, 11)
```

I cannot get any values below 1; is there another way I can create logarithmic spaced values below 1 (and above 0.001)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upper and lower bounds should be passed as exponents, see the [manual](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html). Assuming you are working in base 10, you should thus use `log10(0.001) == -3` and `log10(1000) == 3` as the bounds:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.logspace(-3, 3, 11)
```

Result:

```
[  1.00000000e-03   3.98107171e-03   1.58489319e-02   6.30957344e-02
   2.51188643e-01   1.00000000e+00   3.98107171e+00   1.58489319e+01
   6.30957344e+01   2.51188643e+02   1.00000000e+03]
```

Comment: thanks! I actually misread the manual (or more accurately I just went through it very briefly)